Understanding the Impact of Different Scalers on Deep Learning Model
I am working on a regression task with a dataset that has a heavy right-skewed distribution, and the labels are always positive values. I have preprocessed the labels (features are always scaled using standard scalers) using four different types of scalers from sklearn: Robust, Standard, MinMax, and MaxAbs Scalers. All using default parameters except MinMax where feature range is (-1, 1). For each set of preprocessed labels, I trained deep learning models using the Adam optimizer, keeping everything else constant (i.e., model type, training details, etc.). I repeated the experiments a few times with different but similar datasets.
The results showed that the Robust and Standard scalers performed more or less similarly and better than the others, but the Standard scaler required much longer time (3-4 times more) to train. The performance of MaxAbs followed, and the MinMax scaler was last. All scalers, except for the Robust scaler, required a longer time to train. It's worth noting that since the data is heavily right-skewed, meaning the Robust scaler ends up becoming an identity mapping (to avoid division by zero).
I initially thought the results should be similar across all scalers because they primarily change the range and do not significantly alter the distribution of the data. However, I suspect that minor differences in the distributions of the labels might be causing this difference in performance, but I am not entirely sure.
I would greatly appreciate any feedback or references to relevant research articles that could help me further understand this concept.
Thank you in advance for your help!
